# add icon instead of label in link

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-layout-xml

I'd written this code:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout">
    <label>Cart</label>
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl"/>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>150</position>
</action>
```

But instead of the `label` *Cart* I want to show an image. How could I add image in the above *xml* code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout">
    <label>Cart</label>
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl"/>
    <title>Cart</title>
    <prepare/>
    <urlParams/>
    <position>150</position>
    <liParams />
    <aParams><![CDATA[ class="cart"]]></aParams>
</action>
```

This should add a class `cart` to the `<a>` element. You can add your css on that class that hides the text and displays an icon.